# Central HTML templates to prevent duplicate presentation code in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

In my application I have a lot of UI elements (particuarly buttons) where I am repeating the same code over and over.

For example in multiple views I might have an edit button that is created with the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "SomeController", null, new { @class="button large blue" });
```

The problem here is that I am hard coding the label and styling, so if I want to make changes to the button styling or label, I would have to make them in multiple views. This would be tedious to do, as I would have to track down every button.

So now I am looking at creating a templating mechanism, where I can define a button template in a central area and bring it in to any view I want to use it in.

I have considered two options, which I have tried to sketch out in semi-real world code below.

My question is, am I on the right track here? Which option would be better and for which reasons? Is there already something out there I could consider using, or is there another way which I haven't thought of?

Thanks for your help.

---

### **Web.Config Templates**

Create a custom class that can bring in template configuration from web.config file. For example:

```
 <ui.HtmlTemplates>
      <add templateKey="FormCancel" tag="a" class="form-button large black" />
      <add templateKey="FormSave" tag="input" type="submit" class="form-button large green" />
 </ui.HtmlTemplates>
```

And then could call them in with syntax such as this (method signature is contrived)

```
@HtmlTemplates.Build("FormCancel", Url.Action("Index", "Home"))
```

---

### **Partial View Templates**

Create strongly typed partial views with the template I want.

**ViewModel**

```
public class UiButtonModel
{
    public string Url{ get; set; }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
// Assume the file is called "_Button_FormCancel"
@Model path.to.model.directoy.UiButtonModel

<a href="@Model.Url" class="form-button large black">Cancel</a>
```

**Use**

```
@Html.Partial("_Button_FormCancel", new UiButtonModel(){Url = Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
```

Comment: Why not create your own helper? The config option seem clunky and restricted. I would prefer views to that, but a helper seems ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to create extension methods off of `HtmlHelper` to create prepackaged HTML output using code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static string SaveButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string title = "Save", IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
    {           
        var builder = new TagBuilder("button");

            builder.Attributes.Add("type", "button");

        builder.AddCssClass("form-button");
        builder.AddCssClass("large");
        builder.AddCssClass("green");

        if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        builder.SetInnerText(helper.Encode(title));

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static string CancelButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string title = "Cancel", string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues = null, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
    {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, helper.RouteCollection);

            var builder = new TagBuilder("a");

            builder.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));

        builder.AddCssClass("form-button");
        builder.AddCssClass("large");
        builder.AddCssClass("green");

        if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        builder.SetInnerText(helper.Encode(title));

        return builder.ToString();

    }
}
```

Then just make sure the namespace of `MyHtmlExtensions` is either added to your page directly, or included in all pages via web.config, and use it like this in your view (razor syntax):

```
<div class="form-buttons">
@Html.CancelButton("Index", "Home")
@Html.SaveButton()
</div>
```

This method is particularly well suited for creating output consistently across several solutions, as all you need to do is reference the containing assembly and import the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I create these kinds of templates and put them in my `Views/Shared` folder.

I have templates like:

```
AddButton.cshtml
DeleteButton.cshtml
SaveButton.cshtml

...
```

Then, when I need to call one of them in whatever `View`, I just call this for example:

```
@Html.Partial("SaveButton");
```

Using [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC), it gets even better with compile time checking (no more literal strings):

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.SaveButton)
```

Doing so I have a common/central place to change a specific button config. No need to go view after view to change something.

Comment: I hadn't heard of T4MVC before. Just watched the video on the site of David going through it. Will most definitely be using this moving forward!

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem that css was designed to handle.  I fail to understand the problem.  If you want to make changes, you change the CSS and it affects all the buttons that have that styling.

Part of your problem is that you're using style like "blue".  If you want to change it to red, you have to change it everywhere.

Instead, you should have a class for the button, then you can simply change the button style and you don't have to worry about redefining blue to red.

Comment: this is a totally unrelated comment... So, if I go to Teresina I can find you somewhere... not that mystery/ghosty at all! I'm from Volta Redonda/RJ :D

Comment: Still would have to change the label though.